# run.do_compile error on poky-dunfell release

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto

When I am bitbaking my custom image recipe for STM32MP1 based Avenger96 board I am facing some errors related to `analyze.l:466:19: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]`. I don't understand why I am getting this error as this is the first I am facing it. Please find the below complete log:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-32', 'arm-common', 'arm-32', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'arm-linux', 'arm-linux-gnueabi', 'common']
DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
NOTE: make -j 8
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src'
Making all in libcommon
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libcommon'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libcommon'
Making all in libkbdfile
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libkbdfile'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libkbdfile'
Making all in libkeymap
make[3]: Entering directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libkeymap'
make  all-am
make[4]: Entering directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libkeymap'
../../arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap -I../..   -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap -I. -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/.. -I./.. -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libcommon -I./../libcommon -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile -I./../libkbdfile -DDATADIR=\"/usr/share\" -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/share/locale\" -U_GNU_SOURCE -funit-at-a-time   -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/kbd/2.2.0-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/kbd/2.2.0-r0                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot=                      -fdebug-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native=  -Waggregate-return -Wall -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wdisabled-optimization -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -c -o analyze.lo ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-libtool: compile:  arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap -I../.. -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap -I. -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/.. -I./.. -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libcommon -I./../libcommon -I../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile -I./../libkbdfile -DDATADIR=\"/usr/share\" -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/share/locale\" -U_GNU_SOURCE -funit-at-a-time -g -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fmacro-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/kbd/2.2.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0=/usr/src/debug/kbd/2.2.0-r0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot= -fdebug-prefix-map=/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native= -Waggregate-return -Wall -Wcast-align -Wconversion -Wdisabled-optimization -Wextra -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -c ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/analyze.o
analyze.l: In function 'find_incl_file_near_fn':
analyze.l:141:24: warning: passing argument 2 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:37: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char **'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
analyze.l:141:42: warning: passing argument 3 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:53: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
analyze.l: In function 'find_standard_incl_file':
analyze.l:168:22: warning: passing argument 2 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:37: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
analyze.l:168:40: warning: passing argument 3 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:53: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
analyze.l:197:24: warning: passing argument 2 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:37: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
analyze.l:197:42: warning: passing argument 3 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:53: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
analyze.l: In function 'find_incl_file':
analyze.l:210:27: warning: passing argument 2 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:37: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
analyze.l:210:45: warning: passing argument 3 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:53: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
analyze.l:225:26: warning: passing argument 2 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:37: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char **'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
analyze.l:225:36: warning: passing argument 3 of 'kbdfile_find' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
In file included from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap/kmap.h:36,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/keymap.h:8,
                 from ../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/analyze.c:1:
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/../libkbdfile/kbdfile.h:40:53: note: expected 'char **' but argument is of type 'const char * const*'
   40 | int kbdfile_find(char *fnam, char **dirpath, char **suffixes, struct kbdfile *fp);
      |                                              ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
In file included from analyze.l:10:
analyze.l: In function 'yylex':
analyze.l:466:19: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
../../../kbd-2.2.0/src/libkeymap/contextP.h:79:55: note: in definition of macro 'lk_log_cond'
   79 |    lk_log(ctx, level, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__, ##arg); \
      |                                                       ^~~
analyze.l:466:6: note: in expansion of macro 'ERR'
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[4]: *** [Makefile:604: analyze.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libkeymap'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:476: all] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src/libkeymap'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1083: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:471: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/build'
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
make: *** [Makefile:402: all] Error 2
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Execution of '/root/build-swu-v2/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0/temp/run.do_compile.380' failed with exit code 1
```

When I checked the `sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/kbd`, [add missing string format patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd.git/commit/?id=50eae66fc21ef8e01c69a9d3c1ff3fcb0b2644a0) patch is already available and included in `kbd_2.2.0.bb` recipe. And same patch is also present in `build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/kbd/2.2.0-r0`. But still I am getting above error.

I have no idea what this error means and why am I getting this all of a sudden.

Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should NOT do the following, its likely your code compiles just fine on an older version of GCC, but GCC adds new warnings and errors for security purposes, you should really look at the code and fix it properly, it is also very likely you just need to use a newer version of kbd that builds contains these fixes (kbd is at 2.4.0 in the latest branch: https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/kbd/kbd_2.4.0.bb).

But if you want to temporarily disable the GCC error to check if your build works while you either fix the kbd code or upgrade to a new version of kbd, you could set:

```
CFLAGS += "-Wno-error=format-security"
```

Which will suppress the compilation error, I cannot stress this enough, the fix is to actually fix the kbd code.

Answer (score 0):

quick fix, thanks to aehs29:

copy file
https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/recipes-core/kbd/kbd_2.4.0.bb
to the folder `.../poky/meta/recipes-core/kbd/`

remove file `.../poky/meta/recipes-core/kbd/kbd_2.2.0.bb`

and rebuild

`bitbake -k radxa-minimal-image`